# Help with a node diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to recreate this diagram from a paper for my thesis. The idea would be that I can scale it to different sizes, only use parts of it and insert different nodes like the circles and triangles.

[image]

I have tried reproducing it, but I am quite unexperienced with tikz, so after hours of desperatly trying to make it work I have come up with a huge, unelegant solution, that doesn't really look the way I want it to.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{
positioning,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.misc,
calc,
fit,
matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [pics/myHexagon/.style args={#1/#2/#3}%
{
    code=
    {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mySqrt}{sqrt(3)/2}
    \def\r{#1}
    \def\a{#2}
    \def\c{#3}
    \draw [cm={\r,0,.5*\r,\mySqrt*\r,(0,0)},fill=\c,text=white] 
    (1+\a,0) coordinate (-corner 0) coordinate (-corner 6) 
    -- (\a,1) coordinate (-corner 1)
    -- (-1-\a,1) coordinate (-corner 2)
    -- (-1-\a,0) coordinate (-corner 3)
    -- (-\a,-1)  coordinate (-corner 4)
    -- (1+\a,-1) coordinate (-corner 5)
    -- cycle;
    {asfd}
}
}]

    \draw   (0,0)   pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/RoyalBlue}};
    \draw  (2,0)    pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/DarkMagenta}};
    \draw  (4,0)    pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/RoyalBlue}};
    \draw  (6,0)    pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/DarkMagenta}};


    \draw  (2,-1.5) node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm,fill=red] {L-Ala};
    \draw  (1,-3)   node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow] {D-Glu};
    \draw  (0,-4.5) node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {L-Lys};
    \draw  (0,-6)   node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {D-Ala};

    \draw  (1.7,-4.5)   node [shape=circle,draw,minimum height=.75cm] {Gly};
    \draw  (3,-4.5) node [shape=circle,draw,minimum height=.75cm] {Gly};
    \draw  (4.3,-4.5)   node [shape=circle,draw,minimum height=.75cm] {Gly};
    \draw  (5.6,-4.5)   node [shape=circle,draw,minimum height=.75cm] {Gly};
    \draw  (6.9,-4.5)   node [shape=circle,draw,minimum height=.75cm] {Gly};

    \draw  (8.5,-4.5)   node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {D-Ala};
    \draw  (7.5,-6) node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {L-Lys};
    \draw  (6.5,-7.5)   node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {D-Glu};
    \draw  (5.5,-9) node [shape=ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] {L-Ala};

    \draw   (3.5,-10.5) pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/RoyalBlue}};
    \draw  (1.5,-10.5)  pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/DarkMagenta}};
    \draw  (7.5,-10.5)  pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/RoyalBlue}};
    \draw  (5.5,-10.5)  pic {myHexagon={.6/.3/DarkMagenta}};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Could someone please help me simplify and complete it?
Thanks!

[edit]

I should mention that I used [Scaling only a portion of a TikZ polygon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376913/scaling-only-a-portion-of-a-tikz-polygon) for the polygons.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest using a `chamfered rectangle` for the hexagon, and set a large value of for `chamfered rectangle xsep`. The pgfmanual writes on p. 736

> Sets the distance that the chamfer extends horizontally beyond the
>   node contents (which includes the inner sep). If ⟨length⟩ is large,
>   such that the top and bottom chamfered edges would cross, then
>   ⟨length⟩ is ignored and the chamfered edges are drawn so that they
>   meet in the middle.

and shows a hexagon. Further, you are loading `positioning`, and I would like to suggest using it for relative positioning. (You may also look into chains, but I personally I find this sometimes a bit of an overkill.) So here is a first proposal.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{
positioning,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.misc,
shadows.blur,
calc}
\newcounter{hexa}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my hexa/.style={blur shadow,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle
xsep=2cm,draw,text=white,path picture={%
\draw[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture
bounding box.east)$) in
([xshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.east)
-- ++(-\y1+1pt,\y1-1pt) -- ++(2*\x1,0);}},
my elli/.style={blur shadow,ellipse,draw,text=white,path picture={%
\fill[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture
bounding box.east)$) in ([xshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.east)
to[out=90,in=0,looseness=0.8] ([yshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.north)
to[out=0,in=90,looseness=0.7] cycle;
}},
shaded triangle/.style={blur shadow,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,shape border rotate=0,
inner sep=1pt,draw,inner color=#1!10,outer color=#1}]
    \node[my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc1) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[right=of Glc1,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur1) {MurN Ac};
    \node[right=of Mur1,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc2) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[right=of Glc2,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur2) {MurN Ac};
    %
    \node[below=of Mur1,my elli,fill=DarkGreen] (L-Ala1) {L-Ala};
    \node[below left=8mm and 5mm of L-Ala1,my elli,fill=purple] (D-Glu1)
    {\textsc{d}-Glu};
    \node[below left=8mm and 5mm of D-Glu1,my elli,fill=DarkRed] (L-Lys1)
    {\textsc{l}-Lys};
    \node[right=3mm of L-Lys1,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly1) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly1,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly2) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly2,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly3) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly3,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly4) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly4,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly5) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly5,my elli,fill=cyan] (D-Ala1) {D-Ala};
    \node[below=8mm of L-Lys1,my elli,fill=cyan] (D-Ala2) {D-Ala};
    %
    \node[below left=8mm and -5mm of D-Ala1,my elli,fill=DarkRed] (L-Lys2)
    {\textsc{l}-Lys};
    \node[below left=8mm and -5mm of L-Lys2,my elli,fill=purple] (D-Glu2)
    {\textsc{d}-Glu};
    \node[below left=8mm and -5mm of D-Glu2,my elli,fill=DarkGreen] (L-Ala2) 
    {L-Ala};
    %
    \node[below=of L-Ala2,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur3) {MurN Ac};
    \node[left=of Mur3,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc3) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[left=of Glc3,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur4) {MurN Ac};
    \node[right=of Mur3,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc4) {GlcN Ac};
    %
    \draw (Glc1) -- (Mur1) -- (Glc2) -- (Mur2);
    \draw (Glc2) -- (L-Ala1) -- (D-Glu1) -- (L-Lys1)
    -- (Gly1) -- (Gly2) -- (Gly3) -- (Gly4) -- (Gly5)
    -- (D-Ala1) -- (L-Lys2) -- (D-Glu2) -- (L-Ala2) -- (Mur3) -- 
    (Glc3) -- (Mur4);
    \draw (Mur3) -- (Glc4); 
    \draw (L-Lys1) -- (D-Ala2); 
    % 
    \node[above=5mm of Gly3,shaded triangle=red] (E4) {E4};
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E4.south west) -- ($(Gly2)!0.5!(Gly3)$);
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E4.south east) -- ($(Gly3)!0.5!(Gly4)$);
    \path (Gly5) -- (D-Ala1) coordinate[midway](aux);
    \node[anchor=south,shaded triangle=red] (E5) at (aux|-E4.south) {E5};
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E5.south) -- (aux);
    \node[right=2mm of D-Glu1] (txt1) {NH$_2$};
    \node[left=2mm of D-Glu2] (txt2) {NH$_2$};
    \draw (D-Glu1) -- (txt1);
    \draw (D-Glu2) -- (txt2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make it smaller, you could scale it (e.g. `scale=0.8,transform shape`) and/or adjust the `node distance`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{
positioning,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.misc,
shadows.blur,
calc}
\newcounter{hexa}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3mm,scale=0.8,transform shape,
every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=-0.5ex,shadow yshift=-0.5ex},
my hexa/.style={blur shadow,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle
xsep=2cm,draw,text=white,path picture={%
\draw[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture
bounding box.east)$) in
([xshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.east)
-- ++(-\y1+1pt,\y1-1pt) -- ++(2*\x1,0);}},
my elli/.style={blur shadow,ellipse,draw,text=white,path picture={%
\fill[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture
bounding box.east)$) in ([xshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.east)
to[out=90,in=0,looseness=0.8] ([yshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.north)
to[out=0,in=90,looseness=0.7] cycle;
}},
shaded triangle/.style={blur shadow,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,shape border rotate=0,
inner sep=1pt,draw,inner color=#1!10,outer color=#1}]
    \node[my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc1) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[right=of Glc1,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur1) {MurN Ac};
    \node[right=of Mur1,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc2) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[right=of Glc2,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur2) {MurN Ac};
    %
    \node[below=of Mur1,my elli,fill=DarkGreen] (L-Ala1) {L-Ala};
    \node[below left=8mm and 5mm of L-Ala1,my elli,fill=purple] (D-Glu1)
    {\textsc{d}-Glu};
    \node[below left=8mm and 5mm of D-Glu1,my elli,fill=DarkRed] (L-Lys1)
    {\textsc{l}-Lys};
    \node[right=3mm of L-Lys1,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly1) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly1,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly2) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly2,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly3) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly3,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly4) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly4,my elli,fill=green!80!black] (Gly5) {Gly};
    \node[right=3mm of Gly5,my elli,fill=cyan] (D-Ala1) {D-Ala};
    \node[below=8mm of L-Lys1,my elli,fill=cyan] (D-Ala2) {D-Ala};
    %
    \node[below left=8mm and -2mm of D-Ala1,my elli,fill=DarkRed] (L-Lys2)
    {\textsc{l}-Lys};
    \node[below left=8mm and -2mm of L-Lys2,my elli,fill=purple] (D-Glu2)
    {\textsc{d}-Glu};
    \node[below left=8mm and -2mm of D-Glu2,my elli,fill=DarkGreen] (L-Ala2) 
    {L-Ala};
    %
    \node[below=of L-Ala2,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur3) {MurN Ac};
    \node[left=of Mur3,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc3) {GlcN Ac};
    \node[left=of Glc3,my hexa,fill=DarkMagenta] (Mur4) {MurN Ac};
    \node[right=of Mur3,my hexa,fill=RoyalBlue] (Glc4) {GlcN Ac};
    %
    \draw (Glc1) -- (Mur1) -- (Glc2) -- (Mur2);
    \draw (Glc2) -- (L-Ala1) -- (D-Glu1) -- (L-Lys1)
    -- (Gly1) -- (Gly2) -- (Gly3) -- (Gly4) -- (Gly5)
    -- (D-Ala1) -- (L-Lys2) -- (D-Glu2) -- (L-Ala2) -- (Mur3) -- 
    (Glc3) -- (Mur4);
    \draw (Mur3) -- (Glc4); 
    \draw (L-Lys1) -- (D-Ala2); 
    % 
    \node[above=5mm of Gly3,shaded triangle=red] (E4) {E4};
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E4.south west) -- ($(Gly2)!0.5!(Gly3)$);
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E4.south east) -- ($(Gly3)!0.5!(Gly4)$);
    \path (Gly5) -- (D-Ala1) coordinate[midway](aux);
    \node[anchor=south,shaded triangle=red] (E5) at (aux|-E4.south) {E5};
    \draw[red,thick,-latex] (E5.south) -- (aux);
    \node[right=2mm of D-Glu1] (txt1) {NH$_2$};
    \node[left=2mm of D-Glu2] (txt2) {NH$_2$};
    \draw (D-Glu1) -- (txt1);
    \draw (D-Glu2) -- (txt2);
    \draw (Glc1.west) -- ++ (-0.2,0) (Mur2.east) -- ++ (0.2,0) 
    (Glc4.east) -- ++ (0.2,0) (Mur4.west) -- ++ (-0.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This last version also comes with more realistic shadows, which are opposite to the bright spots.

Comment: Is there a way to make it smaller? But in a way that it is still comfortably readable and you don't have to change every single number by hand.

Comment: @fffff Yes, I added some information on possibilities to scale it.

Comment: when I compile it in texstudio (with xelatex) the shadows are rectangular, how do I fix that?

Comment: @fffff The screenshots show the results of compilations with `xelatex`. Sorry, I never use texstudio. The only additional information I have is that Ulrike Fischer made an update that fixed some issues with `shadow.blur` and `xelatex`, so you may want to update your TeX installation. If that does not help, you could replace `shadows.blur` by `shadows` and `blur shadow` by `drop shadow`.

Comment: one little detail, how can you continue the line on the left and right of the polysaccharides a bit, in order to show that the chain continues?

Comment: @fffff Sure, done.

Answer (score 3):

alternative solution, less fancy (but this can be simple add), with relative positioning of nodes and with some effort to make code short ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols
                }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 6mm,
      start chain = going right,
HEX/.style = {signal, signal to=left and right,
              signal pointer angle=120,
              draw=#1, fill=#1!60, text=white,
              minimum height=10mm, inner sep=-3pt,
              drop shadow,
              on chain, join=by -},
ELL/.style = {ellipse, draw=#1, fill=#1!60, text=white,
              minimum height=8mm, drop shadow,
              on chain, join=by -},
CIR/.style = {circle,  draw=olive, ball color=olive!50,
              minimum height=8mm, drop shadow,
              on chain, join=by -},
TRI/.style = {isosceles triangle, draw=red, fill=red!60,
              isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
              shape border rotate=90}
                    ]

    \node (h11) [HEX=RoyalBlue]     {GlcNAc};
    \node (h12) [HEX=DarkMagenta]   {MurNAc};
    \node (h13) [HEX=RoyalBlue]     {GlcNAc};
    \node (h14) [HEX=DarkMagenta]   {MurNAc};
        \draw (h11.west) -- + (-0.5,0)
              (h14.east) -- + ( 0.5,0);
%
    \node (e11) [ELL=teal,suppress join,
                 below=of h12]         {L-Ala};
    \node (e12) [ELL=orange,
                 below left=of e11,
                 pin=right:\ce{NH2}]  {D-Glu};
    \node (e13) [ELL=teal,  below left=of e12]  {L-Lys};
        \draw (h12) -- (e11);
    \node (c1)  [CIR,suppress join,
                 right=of e13] {Gly};
        \draw (e13) -- (c1);
%
    \node (c1)  [CIR] {Gly};
    \node (c2)  [CIR] {Gly};
    \node (c3)  [CIR] {Gly};
    \node (c4)  [CIR] {Gly};
    \node (e21) [ELL=teal,on chain,join=by -]   {D-Ala};
    \node (e22) [ELL=purple,below left=of e21]  {L-Lys};
    \node (e23) [ELL=purple!50!black,
                 below left=of e22,
                 pin=left:\ce{NH2}]             {D-Glu};
    \node (e24) [ELL=teal,below left=of e23]    {L-Ala};
%
    \node (h23) [HEX=DarkMagenta,
                 below=of e24]                  {MurNAc};
    \node (h22) [HEX=RoyalBlue,left=of h23]     {GlcNAc};
    \node (h21) [HEX=DarkMagenta,left=of h22]   {MurNAc};
    \node (h24) [HEX=RoyalBlue,suppress join,
                 right=of h23]                  {GlcNAc};
        \draw (h21.west) -- + (-0.5,0)
                   (h23) --   (h24)
              (h24.east) -- + ( 0.5,0);
%
    \node (A) [CIR,ball color=yellow, suppress join,
               left=of e11] {A};
    \node (e25) [ELL=teal,suppress join,
                 below=of e13]    {L-Ala};
        \draw (e13) -- (e25);
    \node (t1)  [TRI, above=of c3] {E4};
    \coordinate (t2) at ($(c4)!0.5!(e21)$);
    \node (t3)  [TRI, at=(t2 |- t1)] {E5};
        \draw[-latex,red, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm]
            (A)  edge ($(h12)!0.5!(e11)$)
        %
            (t1) edge ($(c2)!0.5!(c3)$)
            (t1) edge ($(c3)!0.5!(c4)$)
            (t3)  to  (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]