# What does the cm-Option in Tikz do?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a thread someone uses the option "cm" as shown in the following shortened example:

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mySqrt}{sqrt(3)/2}
  \def\r{1}
  \def\a{1}
  \draw [cm={\r,0,.5*\r,\mySqrt*\r,(0,0)}] 
    (1+\a,0) coordinate (-corner 0) coordinate (-corner 3) 
    -- (\a,1) coordinate (-corner 1)
    -- (-\a,1) coordinate (-corner 2)
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the thread: [Scaling only a portion of a TikZ polygon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376913/scaling-only-a-portion-of-a-tikz-polygon) ([@marsupilam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/116936/marsupilam))

### Output

[image: Codeoutput]

### Question

What does this option do and what mean the parameters?

Comment: It’s one of the coordinate transformations (see [`Tikz`](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) manual on the p. 379)

Comment: @Celdor Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes we need to use specific geometric transformations.  See [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), *Section 25.3
Coordinate Transformations, page 378*  for the commands `cm` and `reset cm`:

[image]

A bit explanation:

- `scale=2` is the same as `cm={2, 0, 0, 2, (0,0)}`
- `xscale=2` is the same as `cm={2, 0, 0, 1, (0,0)}`
- `yscale=3` is the same as `cm={1, 0, 0, 3, (0,0)}`
- `shift={(3,4)}` is the same as `cm={1, 0, 0, 1, (3,4)}`
- `xshift=5cm` is the same as `cm={1, 0, 0, 1, (5,0)}`
- `yshift=6cm` is the same as `cm={1, 0, 0, 1, (0,6)}`
- `xslant=1.5` is the same as `cm={1, 0, 1.5, 1, (0,0)}`
- `yslant=3` is the same as `cm={1, 3, 0, 1, (0,0)}`

The following is a small self-tutorial ^^

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[gray!20,thin] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\draw[->,gray,thin] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[below right,black]{$x$}; 
\draw[->,gray,thin] (0,-3.5)--(0,3.5) node[below left,black]{$y$};
\def\mypath{(0,0) rectangle (1,1)}
%\def\mypath{(0,0) circle(1)}
%\def\mypath{(0,0) parabola (2,2)}
%\def\mypath{(0,0) sin (2,1.5)}
%\def\mypath{(0,0) .. controls +(70:2) and +(-100:1) .. (3,2)}


\draw[blue] \mypath;

% [xscale=-3,yscale=-2,shift={(0,-1)}] is the same as cm={-3, 0, 0, -2, (0,-1)}
\draw[cm={-3, 0, 0, -2, (0,-1)},red] \mypath;

% [xslant=1.5] is the same as [cm={1, 0, 1.5, 1, (0,0)}]
\draw[cm={1, 0, 1.5, 1, (0,0)},cyan] \mypath;

\draw[cm={1, 2, 3, -4, (-3,1)},orange] \mypath;

\path (0,4.5) node[align=center]{
\verb|[cm={a, b, c, d, (t_x, t_y)}]|\\[2mm]
$\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}t_x\\t_y\end{pmatrix}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Celdor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31283/celdor) mentioned, it is just a coordinate transformation.

Having

```
\draw[cm={a, b, c, d, (t_x, t_y)}] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
```

every point is transformed by the formula:

[image]

where the point is given by x and y.